# VueJS Mixins Methods Direct Call

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, mixins

I'm testing Mixins on VueJS and I have a question. Is there a way to call an event directly from a Mixins without having to assign it in my `methods`?

**MyMixins.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'

Vue.mixin({
    methods: {
        Alerta(){
            alert('WORK!')
        }
    }
})
```

**app.vue**

```
<template>
   <button v-on:click="AlertaInterno">test</button>
</template>
<script>
   export default{
         methods:{
            AlertaInterno(){
            this.Alerta()
         }
      }
   }
</script>
```

> The code above works. I was wondering how I could invoke the mixin function directly, something like this:

**app.vue**

```
<template>
   <button v-on:click="this.Alerta()">test</button>
</template>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can call it directly. Methods from the mixin are *merged* with the Vue or component they are "mixed in" with. They can be called the same way as any other method.

```js
console.clear()

const Mixin = {
  methods:{
    Alerta(){
      alert("WORK!")
    }
  }
}

new Vue({
  mixins: [Mixin],
  el: "#app"
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.4/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
 <button @click="Alerta">Alert!</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks man! There is any diffence between `@click` or `v-on:click` ?

Comment: Sometimes i see people doing what you did, `@click="alerta"` instead of `@click="alerta()"` using `()` . Whats the difference between these codes?

Comment: @Johnson `@click="alerta"` is shorthand for `v-on:click="alerta"`. There is no difference in how it works, it just saves a few characters. Likewise, you can call `alerta` using either `alerta` or `alerta()`. If `alerta` took parameters, you would want to use `alerta(some, parameters)`. When there are no parameters, you only really need the function name in a click handler.