# Any way to call a mixin (method) from the root instance without using $root?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, mixins

Hello fellow programmers, I need some help:
I'd like to call the following method, without the $root before.
Would that be possible?
I'm using Vue Single File Components.
Ive got the following:

```
//app.js

const mixin = {
methods: {
    makeToast(title = "", content = "", hideAfter = 5000, position = 'b-toaster-bottom-right', append = true) {
        this.$bvToast.toast(`${content}`, {
            title: title,
            toaster: position,
            appendToast: append,
            autoHideDelay: hideAfter,
        })
    }
  }
}

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#vue-app',
    i18n,
    mixins: [mixin],
});
```

which is then callable like

```
<b-button @click="$root.makeToast('title','content here',2000);">CLICK FOR TOAST</b-button>
```

in every component I have. This works great, but I'd like to call the method only via makeToast and not use $root before.
I tried the following when initializing the vue instance:

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#vue-app',
    i18n,
    mounted: function() {
        var makeToast = this.$root.makeToast;
        return makeToast;
    },
    mixins: [mixin],
});
```

also with created, with and without return, etc. many different approaches like this one.
I have no clue, how to get this done.
Any help and also explanation or sidenotes would be greatly greatly appreciated.
Thank you for your time!

Edit: I have tried the [suggested solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46592331/vuejs-mixins-methods-direct-call?rq=1) here, but without luck. It tells me the function is not defined or null or whatever error depending on what I try.
Maybe because I am using this function inside components?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ive found a solution by accident (or rather, reading the docs all over again)

Using Vue Prototype:

```
Vue.prototype.$flash = function (title = "", content = "", hideAfter = 5000, position = 'b-toaster-bottom-right', append = true) {
    this.$bvToast.toast(`${content}`, {
        title: title,
        toaster: position,
        appendToast: append,
        autoHideDelay: hideAfter,
    })
};
```

in the app.js , then you can use $flash(PARAMS HERE) in every component!